# Taking the changes made in AEM author into Local instance

Tags: adobe, aem

I am new to AEM, and would like to know how to take author instance into local instance.  I can take the pushed changes made in project by using git command, then I can build the local by using mvn command. However I can't see the changes that I made in aem prod on local aem.

Can you help me regarding this.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking how you can have the changes made in pages in any of the environment to your local instance, then just create a content package in crxde in the environment from where you want the changes. After creating the package, download it and install in your local instance crxde.

Answer (score 0):

The more direct approach is via the Package Manager, you create a package, enter the desired filters, then build and download. There are automated ways, by using the package manager with curl commands, Grabbit, etc. For local development probably you do not need to bring all the content, especially if the DAM is too big.